# Query over a DateTime field ignoring hours and minutes

Tags: php, sql, date, datetime, mysqli

I am writing a PHP site, in which I use some Mysql to access a DB.

I have a table named `travel`, which used to have a field named `date` from type Date (according to phpMyAdmin), and also I have a PHP variable `$date` from type string which stores a date in the format `"Y-m-d"`

when I needed to get all the elements from the table where the date was the same as the specified in `$date`, I was able to do it with a simple query like this:

`"SELECT * FROM travel WHERE date=$date"`

Now the problem is, I needed to change the date field data-type on the DB, from Date to DateTime, to also store hours and minutes.

On this particular query I am not interested on hours and minutes. I just need to get all the elements from the table where the date is the same as the specified in `$date` **without considering the hours and minutes** stored in the DB field.

what i am suposed to change to achieve this?

For example:

$date = "2030-12-25"

and

database

```
    ID (int)        date (DateTime)
    1           1994-05-30 12:25:00
    2           2030-12-25 15.20:00
    3           2030-12-25 10:30:00
```

I need to get elements with ID 2 and 3.

PS: I know there are similar questions to this, but none of them were useful to me for different reasons

**Edit:**

The mistake that was preventing me to make this query work properly was also present on the old implementation without the time part.

I was omitting single quotes on the $date variable, and it caused the DBMS to not identify the date as a string.

old query:

<strike>`"SELECT * FROM travel WHERE date=$date"`</strike>

`"SELECT * FROM travel WHERE date='$date'"` fixed adding single quotes on `$date`

Also as KIKO Software answered the new one should include quotes too:

`"SELECT * FROM travel WHERE DATE(date) = '$date';"`

Comment: A quick fix would be `DATE(date) = '2030-12-25' `, but this will make your query as *non sargable*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change:

```
"SELECT * FROM travel WHERE date=$date"
```

to:

```
"SELECT * FROM travel WHERE DATE(date) = '$date';"
```

The function `DATE()` gets the date part from the column `date`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `preg_match` to get a substring of the date.

for example: 
`preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/",$date)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to format the datetime field in database by using Date function.

SELECT * FROM travel WHERE DATE(date) = '2018-07-15'